# Slight horizontal scrolling on HTML that is 100%vw

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, width, viewport

I have a simple bootstrap hero/jumbotron that is showing some slight horizontal scrolling and I'm losing my mind trying to figure out what's causing it.

I have the Bootstrap "jumbotron" 100vw but it still shows a gap between the end of the image and scroll bar.

https://codepen.io/bencasalino/pen/yrQgrp

`
  html,
  body {

```
width: 100vw;
```

}
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following lines in css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Because browsers apply default margins/paddings. It's always better to start by clearing default margins/paddings so it won't disturb our calculation.

Comment: Thank you, that helped fix it. I also had a row class with some default values that were also adding to the issue. 

`.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}`

Comment: If you never want horizontal scrollbar then you must kept in mind that width + margins (hor) + padding (hor) + border (outer) of content must not exceed 100%.   That makes sense 